# Recursive algorithm that returns a bool when checking if array[i] == i (must be O(log n))

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, recursion

I'm trying to write a recursive algorithm that returns true if at least one `array[i] == i`. And false if there is no `array[i] = i`.

Also, the parameters needed are `(int * arr, int start, int end)`. So I'll be traversing the array with a pointer. For example:

```
int A[] = {-50,-10,0,1,3,5,8,10};
cout << sameIndex(A,0,7) << endl; //displays 1 (true) since A[5] == 5
```

The part I'm having a lot of trouble is making it O(log n). I can't see where dividing the array into 2 each function call is going to get the correct solution. And trying to come up with the structure of this algorithm is going over my head. Can someone point me in the right direction? I'm not looking for the answer, I just don't know how to start solving this problem recursively, much less in O(log n) time.

Forgot to mention that yes the integers are distinct AND sorted.

I figured it out! Captain Giraffe and Henrik are correct but they use slightly different methods. I chose to go with Captain Giraffe's method because it is slightly easier and more intuitive using binary search. Henrik's uses a little "trick" of finding the solution by subtracting `array[i] - i` to check if they equal 0. Anyways here is the solution:

```
bool sameIndex(int * A, int start, int end)
{
    int mid = (start + end)/2;

    if(start <= end)
    {
        if(*(A + mid) == mid)
            return true;
        else if(*(A + mid) > mid)                   //search left
            return sameIndex(A, start, mid - 1);
        else                                        //search right
            return sameIndex(A, mid + 1, end);
    }
    return false;
}
```

I was making it way harder than it actually was.

Comment: How can this possibly run in `log(n)`? You must check every entry to know that there is no `array[i] == i`.

Comment: If your array is always sorted you can also discard the values that are below the first index 0, and the values that are above the last index (size-1).

Comment: Yeah forgot to mention they are sorted and distinct. I just edited the post.

Comment: So you are essentially just asking how to implement binary search for plain array.

Comment: @Lundin The thing is in binary search you input what you are searching for. Here you have no idea what you're looking for. You're just checking to see if the current index corresponds to the element in the array at that index. Maybe I'm missing something obvious?

Comment: @Ghost_Stark In that case O(log n) doesn't make any sense, the only way to do that is `for(int i=0; i<N; i++) if(array[i] == i) ...`. You always have to start by getting your requirements straight before starting up any form programming.

Comment: @Lundin It is possible. I just solved it. Solution is posted up.

Comment: @Ghost_Stark And that's binary search. You should optimize the code, make it a couple of 100 times more efficient by getting rid of the recursion and use a loop instead. Or just used standard C `bsearch()`.

Comment: @Lundin I know it's more efficient using iteration. But this was just to practice using recursion.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend practising recursion. Or you might end up using it in real-world applications.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do a regular binary search but with the `(array[i] == i)` condition instead of searching for a particular value.

```
If (array[i] > i)
   move left
else
   move right
```

Of course this requires the values to be sorted, but your example indicates that is the case.

Comment: You suggest to do binary search but with array[i] == i, but your code example has array[i] > i. Am I correct in assuming there is an outside condition checking if array[i] == i?

Comment: @Ghost_Stark Indeed you are.  This check is made after  `if (found) return true;`.

Comment: But I don't understand why the check needs to happen if the function already found a solution.

Comment: @Ghost_Stark The `if (array[i] == i) return true;`  ends the algorithm and comes before the branching in the code.  Compare to any other binary search implementation.  All you need to do is change the conditions.

Comment: Oh I see. Alright I think this is exactly what I needed. I'm sort of new to recursion so give me some time before I get back to this.

Answer (score 1):

The answer by @Captain Giraffe is correct. Here is the reason why:

If `array[i]` is a sequence of distinct integers in ascending order, then `array[i] - i` is a sequence of (not necessarily distinct) integers in ascending order. Therefore you can use binary search to search for `0` in this second sequence.

```
If (array[i] - i == 0)
    return true;
If (array[i] - i > 0)
    serach left
else
    search right
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It was helpful in better understanding what Captain Giraffe meant.